# декоратор внутри класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, декоратор

хочу использовать декоратор внутри класса, но не знаю, как туда отправить аргументы из self (чертова инкапсуляция)

```py
class FileCreator:
    def __init__(self, dir):
        self.dir = Path(dir)  # директория для хранения файлов 
        self.data = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  # сегодняшняя дата

    def _save_json(path):  # декоратор
        def decorator(self, func):
            print(self.dir)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                output = func(*args, **kwargs)
                with open(self.dir / path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    json.dump(output, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
                return output
            return wrapper
        return decorator

    @_save_json('data.json')  # заданный аргумент декоратора
    def _make_data_json(self):  # метод, который хочу декорировать
        data = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.data, '%m/%d/%Y')
        data = {'data': data.date().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}
        return data
```

в общем хотелось бы декоратор, в котором можно было бы прописать названия файла и он бы его сохранял как json в опред. папке, которая уже записана в self внутри класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит `_save_json` втаскивать в класс. Понятно, что по логике он относится к нему, но там начинается путаница c self, его нужно определять как staticmethod, и это очень запутывает. Лучше вынести отдельно, т.к. декоратор - это просто функция, которая принимает и возвращает другую функцию, и никакая специфическая для классов логика в нём обычно не нужна.

Вот как-то так должно работать:

```
def _save_json(path):
    def decorator(func):                          # Здесь не нужен self
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):       # А вот как раз здесь self нужен
            output = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            with open(self.dir / path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                json.dump(output, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
            return data                           # А здесь, вероятно, не data, а output?
        return wrapper
    return decorator


class FileCreator:
    def __init__(self, dir):
        self.dir = Path(dir)
        self.data = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    @_save_json('data.json')
    def _make_data_json(self):
        data = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.data, '%m/%d/%Y')
        data = {'data': data.date().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')}
        return data
```

Comment: да, с data->output косякнул))